# To display default user image if image is not present (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a condition in ruby to display default image if no user image is present , if present display the present image.

This is my index.html.slim page:

```
@product.reviews.each do |r|
  a href="#"
  = image_tag r.user.image_url :thumbnail`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you add the code for that in the helper or model, to keep the code clean.

helper method:

```
def user_avatar user
  if user.image.present?
    image_tag user.image_url :thumbnail
  else
    # Assuming you have a default.jpg in your assets folder
    image_tag 'default.jpg'
  end
end
```

view page:

```
@product.reviews.each do |r|
  a href="#"
    = user_avatar r.user
```

Also, from the code i feel like you are using a library like paperclip or carrierwave.

If so in paperclip you can set the default image by placing this code in the model.

```
:default_url => "/assets/:style/missing_avatar.jpg"
```

if you are using carrierwave place this method in your uploader file.

```
def default_url
  "/images/fallback/default.png"
end
```

Comment: i added function in review model but says undefined method user-avatar  , iam using carrierwave.

Comment: @sreena user-avatar is a helper, you need to place that method in the `application_helper.rb` or `user_helper.rb`. Since you are using carrierwave use the last method i suggested with the default_url method

Comment: thanks .. it worked thanks a lot.. now avatar image size also good
:

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using paperclip or something to save your images to the database, you can check if image exists by having

```
if r.user.image.present?
   = image_tag r.user.image_url :thumbnail
else
   = image_tag 'your default image path'
end
```

you should check your image gem to get find out whether this is valid as I don't know what kind of setup you have.

Comment: this code  works, when i tried like if r.user.image.present? instaed of exists  ...thanks a lot :)

Comment: fixed per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I managed to take care of this by using erb inside of the view used to display a user.

One nice thing about this approach is you won't need to save a default photo multiple times for multiple users. You can keep one inside of assets/images and just rely on it.

I was using Active Storage and the following gems to take care of uploading and resizing of photos:

```
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
```

and wrote the following code inside of the necessary view:

```
  <% if user.image.attached? %>
   <%= image_tag user.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [200, 200]) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag("default.jpg", alt: "A stern frog", width: "200") %>
  <% end %>
```

Just make sure you have a photo named default.jpg inside of assets/images